# How to append more than 200 downloaded tweets to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, tweepy

I am downloading more than twitters rate cap using a loop; however, when I try to append the list it returns an empty dataframe.

My function looks like:

IN:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tweepy
from datetime import timedelta

def get_tweets(handle):
    batch_count_for_tweet_downloads = 200
    try:
        alltweets = []
        tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=handle,
                                           count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads,
                                           exclude_replies=True,
                                           include_rts=False,
                                           lang="en",
                                           tweet_mode="extended")
        # ---GET MORE THAN 200 TWEETS
        alltweets.extend(tweets)
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        oldest_datetime = pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(oldest))[:-10]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(f"Getting Tweets For " + handle + ", After: " + oldest_datetime)
        while len(tweets) > 0:
            tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=handle, count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads, max_id=oldest)
            alltweets.extend(tweets)
            oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
            print("Count: " + f"...{len(alltweets)} " + handle + " Tweets Downloaded")
        #---
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweets.user.screen_name for tweets in alltweets], columns=['Handle'])
        df['Tweets'] = np.array([tweets.full_text for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Date'] = np.array([tweets.created_at - timedelta(hours=4) for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Len'] = np.array([len(tweets.full_text) for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Like_count'] = np.array([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets])
        df['RT_count'] = np.array([tweets.retweet_count for tweets in alltweets])
        total_tweets.extend(alltweets)
        print(handle + " Total Tweets Extracted: {}".format(len(alltweets)))
    except:
        pass
    return df
```

As you can see I need some help merging the loop into the function.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT 1: (What my code looks like now)**

IN:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

handles = ['@MrML16419203', '@d00tn00t']

consumerKey = 'x'
consumerSecret = 'x'
accessToken = 'x'
accessTokenSecret = 'x'

authenticate = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
authenticate.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api_twitter = tweepy.API(authenticate, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

total_tweets = []
def get_tweets(handle):
    batch_count_for_tweet_downloads = 200
    try:
        alltweets = []
        tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=handle,
                                           count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads,
                                           exclude_replies=True,
                                           include_rts=False,
                                           lang="en",
                                           tweet_mode="extended")
        alltweets.extend(tweets)
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        oldest_datetime = pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(oldest))[:-10]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(f"Getting Tweets For " + handle + ", After: " + oldest_datetime)
        while len(tweets) > 0:
            tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=handle, count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads, max_id=oldest)
            alltweets.extend(tweets)
            if len(alltweets) > 0:
                oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
            else:
                pass
            print("Count: " + f"...{len(alltweets)} " + handle + " Tweets Downloaded")
        print('---Total Downloaded: ' + str(len(alltweets)) + ' for ' + handle + '---')
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweets.user.screen_name for tweets in alltweets], columns=['Handle'])
        df['Tweets'] = np.array([tweets.full_text for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Date'] = np.array([tweets.created_at - timedelta(hours=4) for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Len'] = np.array([len(tweets.full_text) for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Like_count'] = np.array([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets])
        df['RT_count'] = np.array([tweets.retweet_count for tweets in alltweets])

        print([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets])
        print(np.array([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets]))

        total_tweets.extend(alltweets)
        print("----------Total Tweets Extracted: {}".format(df.shape[0]) + "----------")
    except:
        pass
    return df
df = pd.DataFrame()
for handle in handles:
    df_new = get_tweets(handle)
    df = pd.concat((df, df_new))
print(df)
```

OUT:

```
Getting Tweets For @MrML16419203, After: 2011-03-19 07:03:53
Count: ...136 @MrML16419203 Tweets Downloaded
---Total Downloaded: 136 for @MrML16419203---
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
----------Total Tweets Extracted: 136----------
Getting Tweets For @d00tn00t, After: 2009-11-27 19:18:58
Count: ...338 @d00tn00t Tweets Downloaded
Count: ...530 @d00tn00t Tweets Downloaded
Count: ...546 @d00tn00t Tweets Downloaded
Count: ...546 @d00tn00t Tweets Downloaded
---Total Downloaded: 546 for @d00tn00t---
           Handle   Tweets                Date  Len  Like_count  RT_count
0    MrML16419203   132716 2020-09-02 02:18:28  6.0         0.0       0.0
1    MrML16419203   432881 2020-09-02 02:04:23  6.0         0.0       0.0
2    MrML16419203   973625 2020-09-02 02:04:09  6.0         0.0       0.0
3    MrML16419203  1234567 2020-09-02 01:55:10  7.0         0.0       0.0
4    MrML16419203   225865 2020-09-02 01:27:11  6.0         0.0       0.0
..            ...      ...                 ...  ...         ...       ...
541      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
542      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
543      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
544      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
545      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN

[682 rows x 6 columns]
```

As you can see for handles which have less than 200 tweets the dataframe gets populated. However, not for handles which contain more than 200 tweets.

Comment: can you add the missing imports?

Comment: Did you see the "Total Tweets Extracted" print and was the number greater than 0?

Comment: I don't understand _when I try to append the list it returns an empty dataframe._ Are you saying that `return df` returns a DataFrame with no rows or columns? What is the "append the list" part? which list?

Comment: As an aside, your try/except needs some work. If you get an exception before creating the dataframe, `df` isn't defined and you'll get an exception for that. Perhaps it would be better to returned a canned dataframe or `None`. And of course, catching all exceptions is risky, you miss the legitimate errors. When you don't get the return you want but supress all exceptions... it makes one wonder!

Comment: @anon01 Added Imports

Comment: @tdelaney When I print total_tweets just before "except:" it prints an empty dataframe. It seems that the dataframe when printed (outside the function) returns only values for the Handle column

Comment: @tdelaney after some more experimenting i've found that any iterated handle populates only the handle column of the dataframe and returns NaN or NaT for every other column. Any ideas? I'm new to python!

Comment: Let me see if I understand, suppose `df["Handles"]` has length 20, then the dataframe would have columns for `Tweets`, `Date`, `Len`, and etc..., but they would have 20 NaN or NaT? Its like the `np.array` is not filling. It could be a problem with data type guessing. You could print a list and its array, `print([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets])` plus `print(np.array([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets]))` then we can see what they are.

Comment: It could be the numpy to pandas conversion. You can create the columns with the lists directly: `df['Tweets'] = [tweets.full_text for tweets in alltweets]`. Or create a `dict` where the keys are column names and the values are lists: df = pd.DataFrame({"Handle":[tweets.user.screen_name for tweets in alltweets], "Tweets":[tweets.full_text for tweets in alltweets], etc...})`. And to note, numpy and pandas do a lot of surprizing things that can make a seasoned python programmer weep. They are powerful tools but have a significant learning curve.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you for the help and attention. Any handle that has less than 200 tweets populates the dataframe with the correct data points (Tweets, Dates, Len, ... columns get populated). Any handle with greater than 200 tweets returns NaN and NaT values for those columns. The print functions return a list of all zeroes. I tried creating a dictionary and tried creating columns directly without np.array to no avail. Any other suggestions? I've editted my code above with the most recent iteration of my code.

Comment: `pd.concat` will fill non-existent columns with `NaN` and `NaT` ("not a number" and "not a time"). My guess: After your first 200 tweets, an exception is raised after the new df is created but before its populated with the other columns. Change your exception to `except Exception as e: print("FATAL ERROR", e)` to see.

Comment: @tdelaney i'm getting back: FATAL ERROR 'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text' would merge work better than concat?

Comment: @YUragun - No, the problem is that with no data, the column has to be extended with something so that they are all the same length. It looks to me like you are being throttled by twitter. You could experiment with the other fields to see if they have anything, but I think the solution is an upgraded account.

Comment: @tdelaney I don't think so as the total number of tweets downloaded is less than 3200. Anyways thanks for your help. I'll try and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles across this I got it to work:

```
def get_tweets(screen_name):
batch_count_for_tweet_downloads = 200
try:
    alltweets = []
    tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name,
                                       count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads,
                                       exclude_replies=True,
                                       include_rts=False,
                                       lang="en")
    alltweets.extend(tweets)
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    oldest_datetime = pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(oldest))[:-10]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print(f"Getting Tweets For " + handle + ", After: " + oldest_datetime)
    while len(tweets) > 0:
        tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads,
                                           max_id=oldest)
        alltweets.extend(tweets)
        if len(alltweets) > 0:
            oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        else:
            pass
        print("Count: " + f"...{len(alltweets)} " + handle + " Tweets Downloaded")
    outtweets = [
        [tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text, tweet.created_at, len(tweet.text),
         tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count] for tweet in alltweets]
    df_tweet_function = pd.DataFrame(outtweets,
                                     columns=['Handle', 'Tweets', 'Date', 'Len', 'Like_count', 'RT_count'])
    print('----------Total Downloaded: ' + str(len(alltweets)) + ' for ' + handle + '----------')
except tweepy.error.TweepError:
    pass
return df_tweet_function
```

df = pd.DataFrame()
if **name** == '**main**':
for handle in handles:
get_tweets(handle)
df = df.append(get_tweets(handle))
print("---------------TOTAL TWEETS EXTRACTED: {}".format(df.shape[0]) + "---------------")