# How to collect more than 200 tweets for multiple twitter handles / users?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to collect more than Twitter's rate limit of 200 Tweets for a given number of users.

However, my code only populates the dataframe when the user has less than 200 tweets and fails to append values to the dataframe from users that have more than 200 tweets.

Complete code
IN:

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

handles = ['@MrML16419203', '@d00tn00t']

consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret = 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'
authenticate = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
authenticate.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api_twitter = tweepy.API(authenticate, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

total_tweets = []
def get_tweets(handle):
    batch_count_for_tweet_downloads = 200
    try:
        alltweets = []
        tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=handle,
                                           count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads,
                                           exclude_replies=True,
                                           include_rts=False,
                                           lang="en",
                                           tweet_mode="extended")
        alltweets.extend(tweets)
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
        oldest_datetime = pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(oldest))[:-10]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print(f"Getting Tweets For " + handle + ", After: " + oldest_datetime)
        
        while len(tweets) > 0:
            tweets = api_twitter.user_timeline(screen_name=handle, count=batch_count_for_tweet_downloads, max_id=oldest)
            alltweets.extend(tweets)
            if len(alltweets) > 0:
                oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
            else:
                pass
            print("Count: " + f"...{len(alltweets)} " + handle + " Tweets Downloaded")

        print('---Total Downloaded: ' + str(len(alltweets)) + ' for ' + handle + '---')

        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweets.user.screen_name for tweets in alltweets], columns=['Handle'])
        df['Tweets'] = np.array([tweets.full_text for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Date'] = np.array([tweets.created_at - timedelta(hours=4) for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Len'] = np.array([len(tweets.full_text) for tweets in alltweets])
        df['Like_count'] = np.array([tweets.favorite_count for tweets in alltweets])
        df['RT_count'] = np.array([tweets.retweet_count for tweets in alltweets])

        total_tweets.extend(alltweets)

        print("----------Total Tweets Extracted: {}".format(df.shape[0]) + "----------")

    except:
        pass
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame()

for handle in handles:
    df_new = get_tweets(handle)
    df = pd.concat((df, df_new))

print(df)
```

OUT:

```
           Handle   Tweets                Date  Len  Like_count  RT_count
0    MrML16419203   132716 2020-09-02 02:18:28  6.0         0.0       0.0
1    MrML16419203   432881 2020-09-02 02:04:23  6.0         0.0       0.0
2    MrML16419203   973625 2020-09-02 02:04:09  6.0         0.0       0.0
3    MrML16419203  1234567 2020-09-02 01:55:10  7.0         0.0       0.0
4    MrML16419203   225865 2020-09-02 01:27:11  6.0         0.0       0.0
..            ...      ...                 ...  ...         ...       ...
536      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
537      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
538      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
539      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
540      d00tn00t      NaN                 NaT  NaN         NaN       NaN
```

As you can see any user that has more than 200 tweets returns NaN and NaT values even though my console shows that the while loop is downloading these data points.

I've tried multiple solutions (such as cursors) to no avail and receive a length mismatch error when trying to only pull tweets from accounts with over 200 tweets. This is because the dataframe returned is empty (apart from the 'Handles' column) and is observable as such when exported out into a CSV.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out, please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747136/how-to-append-more-than-200-downloaded-tweets-to-dataframe/63756660#63756660

Comment: should you close this question? so we have one less duplicate

Comment: @RichieV how do i close questions?